# Creating custom size PDF document with Debenu Quick PDF

Tags: c#

Hi I am using Debenu Quick PDF Lib.
I couldn't see any sample or info about creating custom size PDF document.
For example I want to create a new document in size of 80mm x 100mm in 300 dpi. Is that possible with QP ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user3253797,

QP.SetMeasurementUnits(1);          // Set the measurement units to mm
  QP.SetPageDimensions(80.0, 100.0);  // Set the page size to 80mm x 100mm

In a PDF file there is no DPI value as nearly all the values in a PDF are based on floating point numbers.

When SetMeasurementUnits is set to 1 then all values you use for drawing are assumed to be in millimetres.  ie.  QP.DrawLine(0, 0, 25.4, 25.4);  will draw a diagonal line from the bottom left corner (0,0) to a point 1 inch up and 1 inch to the right of the bottom corner of the page.  If you need the Origin to be based a the top right then you need to call QP.SetOrigin(1); first.

Also, the "Debenu Quick PDF Library 10 Developer Guide.pdf" is the perfect place to start to learn about Debenu Quick PDF Library.  It explains the basics of creating PDF files using the library and some of the fundamentals of PDF files.

Andrew.

Disclaimer: I work for Debenu.